# encoding nested json objects in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, jsp, servlets

I have a json code in JAVA, I would like to know its equivalent code in PHP.

```
    JSONArray objArr = new JSONArray();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    for(int i =0 ;i<4;i++)
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name", "punith"+i);
        obj.put("id", "123"+i);
        System.out.println(obj);
        objArr.add(obj);
    }
    out.println(objArr);
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    result.put("result",objArr);
    out.println("<br>");
    out.println(result);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    objArr = (JSONArray) result.get("result");
    obj = (JSONObject) objArr.get(0);
    out.println("<br>");
```

> ```
> O/P of this code is :: 
>
> {"result":[{"name":"punith0","id":"1230"},{"name":"punith1","id":"1231"},{"name":"punith2","id":"1232"},{"name":"punith3","id":"1233"}]}
> ```

I would like to get the same result with php code. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are

```
$resultArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    $element = array("name"=>"punith$i", "id"=>"123$i");
    array_push($resultArray, $element);
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$resultArray));
```

Comment: Thank u that really matters me a lot .

Answer (score 0):

In php you have

```
json_encode($object);
```

Which stringify the object